# add a variable to the resolver output with sceptre

Tags: aws-cloudformation, sceptre

I have scenario in describing a stack in sceptre where I have to append an already known port number to the hostname/ip that I can get from the resolver like this:

```
LdapServerURL: !stack_output_external some-stack::Host
```

I wish to have the "LdapServerURL" be intepreted or have a value like this:-
Host:389
where 389 is the known port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that isn't supported at the moment.
could you add the port to the output, as URLs can contain ports.

Failing that i wrote something once to solve this: https://github.com/cloudreach/sceptre_combine_resolvers, It's designed for sceptre v2, but if you copy the `sceptre_combine_resolvers.py` into `resolvers` in your repo it should work